# Why this text is not showing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In [this](http://www.fasm.edu.br/webmaster/Site-Itaquera/home.php#one) page, there's a box on the right side with tabs, and the Blog tab is not showing the text, why?

Comment: Check out this [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review?referrer=aWNm_PdciyFqjFW8CUacGw2 "code review"). If you think it might be useful show your support and help get it to beta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Text color is white, as is the background.

```
a.linkblog:link {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: oh gosh.. it's defined as white in [this css](http://www.fasm.edu.br/webmaster/Site-Itaquera/css/style.css).. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because the link color is set to `white`:

```
a.linkblog:link {
    color: white;
}
```

Now, next time use a tool like Firebug or the WebKite Inspector (hit `Ctrl + Shift + I` in Safari / Chrome) and find it out yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the Css

```
a.linkblog:link {
  color:#FFF;
}
```

to something like

```
a.linkblog:link {
  color:#000;
}
```